# thread safe writing to a stream in c++ by multiple thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance-testing

I am trying to create multiple threads and try to find out the scheduling order and when they finish. 
Every time a thread got CPU it perform some computation , then it waits for some x time( 1000ns) as a busy wait 
and then go for sleep. Every time one thread got CPU it also prints the time so that I can later find the 
time when a particular thread got CPU and the order.

To make thread-safe , I am using mutex, but still it is not giving correct result.
Where I am making mistakes ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am using g++ under linux.

**Note:** I can't use file as in that case file open/close incurs overhead.

Here is my program output

> ```
> Output :
>
> $ sort -t , -k4,4n -k5,5n -k6,6n >a.txt
> ```

```
$ head a.txt 
thread,   thread_no, iteration, time_min, time_sec, time_microsec    
foo,
foo,14,987
foo,32
foo,32,985,
foo,57,970
foo,71,933,
foo,71,933,
foo,71,933,
foo,71,933,

$ tail a.txt  
thread,   thread_no, iteration, time_min, time_sec, time_microsec
foo,98,991,40,05,935379 
foo,98,992,40,05,935442 
foo,98,993,40,05,935506
```

> ```
> foo,98,994,40,05,935569 
> foo,98,995,40,05,935633 
> foo,98,996,40,05,935697 
> foo,98,997,40,05,935760 
> foo,98,998,40,05,935824 
> foo,98,999,40,05,937914 
> foo,98,1000,40,05,937994
> ```

As per comment of Bart van Nierop after adding out.flush() before releasing mutex,

here is the result.$ head a.txt

```
foo,
foo,
foo,48,991,
foo,65,
foo,95,
foo,97
foo,10,1,15,59,288329 
foo,10,1,15,59,288329 
foo,10,1,15,59,288329
```

**Here is my program**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex
#include <sstream>

#define BILLION  1000000000L
#define NUM_THREADS 100

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

using namespace std;


std::string now_str()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    struct tm *tm;
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    tm=localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
    char buf[40];
    sprintf(buf,"%02d,%02d,%ld ", tm->tm_min,tm->tm_sec, tv.tv_usec); 
    return buf;
}


std::ostringstream out;  
/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread*/
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{ 
      int s,j;
      pthread_attr_t gattr;

      // Assigning SCHED_RR policy 

      j = SCHED_RR;
      s = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&gattr, j);
      if (s != 0) 
        printf( "pthread_attr_setschedpolicy");

      s = pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(&gattr, &j);
      if (s != 0)
        printf( "pthread_attr_getschedpolicy");


    struct timespec start, stop;
    double accum;

    char *str;
    int i = 0,k=0;

    str=(char*)arg;

    while(i < 1000)
    {

        ++i;

        // do something here

        mtx.lock(); 
        out << "\nfoo," <<str<<","<<i<<"," <<now_str(); // note the timing of thread
        mtx.unlock();  


    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) 
    {
          perror( "clock gettime" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // busy wait for 1000ns
    do

    { 
        if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) 
        {
              perror( "clock gettime" );
              exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

        accum = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )* BILLION + ( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec ) ;

    }while(accum < 1000);

        // block the thread, to allow other thread to run
        usleep(1);
    }
    std::cout<<out.str();

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t pth[NUM_THREADS];  
    int i = 0;
pthread_create(&pth[0],NULL, threadFunc,  (void *) "0"); 
pthread_create(&pth[1],NULL, threadFunc,  (void *) "1"); 
.
.
.

pthread_create(&pth[98],NULL, threadFunc,  (void *) "98"); 
pthread_create(&pth[99],NULL, threadFunc,  (void *) "99"); 

    for(int k=0;k<NUM_THREADS;k++)
    pthread_join(pth[k],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream (`out::flush()`) before releasing the mutex?

Comment: @BartvanNierop, thanks for commenting. I didn't do that. I will do it and post the result.

Comment: @BartvanNierop have tried with out.flush(); option, but no success. Still getting almost same result. foo,
foo,
foo,48,991,
foo,65,
foo,95,
foo,97
foo,10,1,15,59,288329 
foo,10,1,15,59,288329 
foo,10,1,15,59,288329 .

Comment: I am adding new result in original post as it is in not clear format in comment.

Comment: g++ 4.6.3 with kernel 2.6.32 version. compile as  g++ -std=c++0x thread_multi.cpp -o t -lpthread -lrt

Comment: `-pthread` would be the first thing I'd add (let the compiler, not just the linker, know it's using threads). If that doesn't help, POSIX mutex or boost. 4.6 was a long time ago.

Comment: @Cubbi there is no change in output, BTW what makes a difference between -lpthread and -pthread ? here I am facing problem of writing into same stream by multiple threads.

Comment: I was sloppy. You need to lock `std::cout<<out.str();`

Comment: @bholanath one links against a library, the other #define's `_REENTRANT` (and potentially more) and links against a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little searching on google and it looks like [ostringstream is not thread safe](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/4--LgXQy8q0).

To get what you want you could roll your own logging.

One method would be to write to the end of a large buffer:

```
uint64_t offset = 0;
char buffer[ 200000 ];
```

Write to it using a mutex:

```
mtx.lock(); 
offset += sprintf( buffer + offset, "\nfoo,%s,%d,%s", str, i, now_str().c_str() );
mtx.unlock();
```

Comment: should I make buffer as local or global variable ?

Comment: It would need to be accessible after your threads are done so you can print the contents. So global seems the logical choice. It won't be deallocated while you're trying to use it

Answer (score 4):

You hold the mutex while populating `std::ostringstream out`, but not while streaming it to `std::cout`. So, one thread holding the mutex can be mutating `out` at the same time another without the mutex is reading from it.

The simplest fix would be protect your `std::cout<<out.str();` line with the same mutex.

If you care about performance, you can make the global `std::ostringstream out` a function-local variable (I don't know why you have so many globals in the first place), so that each thread has its own copy. Then, while you should still protect the global `cout`, you don't need the mutex around formatting your own stream.

Comment: thanks it's working now. I was thinking while a variable is global , only one copy among threads is there, and while make a local variable every thread makes it own copy.